# Hide datagrid row on dropdown change

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, datagrid

I have a data grid, which is populated with the data. Now on dropdown change, i need to hide some of the rows in data grid.

```
E.g. data grid has value #dgNew

Apple
Banana
Orange
Football
BaseBall
IceCream
Pie

<b>Dropdownvalue #ddlCheck</b>:
Fruits(1)
Sports(2)
Deserts(3)
```

Now when we select fruits all other value should be hidden. If we select sports only sport related value should be visible.

How can we do this through jquery/javascript on client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having your `select` input and `datagrid` set with its values and `id`s or `classes` set for each group - since you wasn't clear about what is needed I took the liberty of setting up an example using `id` for each `table row`, nothing stops you from instead of changing `id` in rows that have all elements from the group in columns to `classes` and a row for each element - a simple markup:

```
<select id="dgNew">
  <option value="0">...</option>
  <option value="1">fruits</option>
  <option value="2">sports</option>
  <option value="3">desserts</option>
</select>
<table>
  <tr id="1">
    <td>apple</td>
    <td>banana</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td>baseball</td>
    <td>football</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="3">
    <td>icecream</td>
    <td>pie</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Every row must be initialized with CSS `display` set to `none`:

```
table tr{
  display:none;    
}
```

Now we need the `change` event to fire when the `select` value is changed so we can display the correct group of items:

```
$("#dgNew").change(function(){    
   $('table tr').css("display","none");
   if($("#dgNew").val() > 0)
   {        
      $('#'+$("#dgNew").val()).css("display","block");
   }
});
```

**Example FIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/qPfJ6/1/